# Javascript error on product page in magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2.4

After upgradeing to **Magento 2.2.4** there seems to be an **error** on the **product page** where the **javascript** its not working properly (see the screenshot).

I am using **Porto**.
Any ideas?

[image: Javascript error on product page in magento 2.2.4]

Comment: The error you refer to is the invalid JSON? Or do you mean the duplicate element IDs? Did you check where that JSON is coming from?

Comment: The error is the invalid JSON (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1206).

Comment: Can you check the source code of this page? Most properly, the issue cames from product name with ' which broken the JSON string.

Comment: You should post that Tran, so it seems the right answer

Answer (score 6):

In

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

replace

```
"arrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/arrows"); ?>,

"showCaption": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/caption"); ?>,
```

with:

```
"arrows": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/arrows"); ?>",

"showCaption": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/caption"); ?>",
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by renaming the following file:

```
app/design/frontend/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/_gallery.phtml
```

After that run all magento commands. Hope this helps